# natbib error when compiling latex

Tags: natbib

I am trying to send an article written in latex but I have a problem with natbib.
Appart that it doesn't like my settings, it puts the citation as:

Ustun and Abbak 2010. Ustun A and Abbak RA (2010) On global and regional
spectral evaluation of global geopotential models. J Geophys Eng, 7, 4, 369379.

So, it repits the authors...

Could somebody help me?
Regards,
Eugenia

### My settings are:

```
\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}     % onecolumn (ditto)
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lineno}
%\usepackage{float}
%\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{placeins}
%

% Insert the name of "your journal" with
 \journalname{Acta Geodaetica et Geophysica}
%
\begin{document}

TTTTtext \cite{ustun} blabla


\bibliographystyle{spbasic}      % basic style, author-year citations


%\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}      % mathematics and physical sciences
%\bibliographystyle{spphys}       % APS-like style for physics
%\bibliography{}   % name your BibTeX data base

% Non-BibTeX users please use
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem[Ustun and Abbak 2010]{ustun}
Ustun A and Abbak RA (2010) On global and regional spectral evaluation of global geopotential models. J Geophys Eng, 7, 4, 369\-379.


% and use \bibitem to create references. Consult the Instructions
% for authors for reference list style.
%
% etc
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}

\end
```

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) natbib is best used with `bibtex` and external bibliographih data. You are manually filling in the data for `thebibliography` env. `natbib` expects the data in `\bibitem[...]` to be specified in a very specify way, your data does not comply to that specification.

Answer (score 1):

dalief is right. If you still want to keep `\bibitem[...]`, the following will work (borrowed from a `.bbl` file):

```
\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Ustun and Abbak}{Ustun and Abbak}{2010}]{ustun}
Ustun A and Abbak RA (2010) On global and regional spectral evaluation of 
global geopotential models. J Geophys Eng, 7, 4, 369--379.
```

I would use `bibtex` as dalief comments. (Also note the pages part. `\-` is for optional hyphenation.)